# Constant VPN issues on El Capitan

Tags: macos, vpn

I installed an el capitan update about two weeks ago, and since then I've had constant issues connecting my macbook pro to my work VPN.

I can connect ok, but after only a few minutes (usually-- it can be as long as 45 min and as short as about 2 minutes) the VPN dies off.

Tailing the VPN logs, it all looks ok for a while, then starts repeating the following:

```
Thu Apr 14 13:01:03 2016 : No DHCP server replied
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x5 88 ce 83 e3 a6 12 ea 7b 43 ac 98 7f de 47 5c 2c 6f 86 f7 7c 8a 5e 0a c6 1d b1 23 c7 95 92 a1 f0 ...]
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x88ce
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x6 62 7b 8e 7c b2 95 42 8f 7e 38 88 37 32 bb bb 79 7a 10 e5 e8 35 76 99 20 7b bd 83 1c bc b7 b0 4c ...]
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x627b
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x7 00 4d fb fc 33 73 bc 0c 25 9b f0 eb 3a 6c 93 21 d6 9f ec e1 f5 19 71 6d ff 7d 8b 3a 02 f2 e6 e4 ...]
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x4d
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x8 d8 ac 17 1e 35 e3 59 3b 7d 0c 34 0b 4f 87 d3 86 6a 5c 03 dc 09 7b e0 a7 17 79 5f 5e 73 b6 ac 26 ...]
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xd8ac
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x9 00 3b d8 5e 73 a1 e5 fd ff 33 3c 27 0d 5c aa 46 8c 1c 85 33 e0 ac 5d e0 f5 fc 50 bc 30 af 23 23 ...]
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x3b
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0xa 00 ef a9 de 91 fe 98 7b a3 db f4 32 08 c0 af 6b ff 86 31 09 e4 23 dd ef 53 df b4 18 b2 33 81 c0 ...]
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xef
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0xb 00 27 41 a2 f0 b1 53 69 71 fa ae 58 fb 33 c2 5a 1e dc 10 ce 4d f8 ca bc 28 d6 ef 8a 95 7a 60 03 ...]
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x27
Thu Apr 14 13:03:08 2016 : rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0xc 00 c5 76 9b 78 e4 44 b6 df 7c ea 61 41 a2 17 12 e3 ab 42 2c 11 a6 37 72 15 30 93 10 81 7b 69 7d ...]
```

Has anyone seen this before? Any idea of workaround or things to try?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [TunnelBlick](https://tunnelblick.net/). Whenever I run into issues with the default VPN client TunnelBlick works much better. It even has options (like forcing full tunneling) that the built-in one doesn't.